# virtualenv: pre-installed with packages on creating virtual environment

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, virtualenv

I created a virtual environment using command `virtualenv env` on my terminal. On using `pip freeze > requirements.txt` after activating the virtual environment, I was a bunch of packages preinstalled.

Here is `requirements.txt`:

```py
appdirs==1.4.3
CacheControl==0.12.6
certifi==2019.11.28
chardet==3.0.4
colorama==0.4.3
contextlib2==0.6.0
distlib==0.3.0
distro==1.4.0
html5lib==1.0.1
idna==2.8
ipaddr==2.2.0
lockfile==0.12.2
msgpack==0.6.2
packaging==20.3
pep517==0.8.2
progress==1.5
pyparsing==2.4.6
pytoml==0.1.21
requests==2.22.0
retrying==1.3.3
six==1.14.0
urllib3==1.25.8
webencodings==0.5.1
```

I haven't installed them and then, why are they there? I don't want any obsolete packages in the project which takes space and time.
Output on `virtualenv env` command:

```sh
created virtual environment CPython3.7.5.final.0-64 in 297ms
  creator CPython3Posix(dest=/home/techmirtz/projects/Django/apps/polls/env, clear=False, global=False)
  seeder FromAppData(download=False, pkg_resources=latest, requests=latest, setuptools=latest, wheel=latest, CacheControl=latest, chardet=latest, webencodings=latest, certifi=latest, distlib=latest, idna=latest, colorama=latest, distro=latest, progress=latest, msgpack=latest, pep517=latest, appdirs=latest, urllib3=latest, pip=latest, html5lib=latest, pyparsing=latest, contextlib2=latest, six=latest, lockfile=latest, packaging=latest, pytoml=latest, retrying=latest, ipaddr=latest, via=copy, app_data_dir=/home/techmirtz/.local/share/virtualenv/seed-app-data/v1.0.1.debian)
  activators BashActivator,CShellActivator,FishActivator,PowerShellActivator,PythonActivator,XonshActivator
```

Also, I activated virtual environment by `source env/bin/activate`.
Then, I tried `conda list`:

```
# packages in environment at /home/techmirtz/anaconda3:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
_anaconda_depends         2019.03                  py37_0  
_ipyw_jlab_nb_ext_conf    0.1.0                    py37_0  
_libgcc_mutex             0.1                        main  
alabaster                 0.7.12                   py37_0  
anaconda                  custom                   py37_1  
anaconda-client           1.7.2                    py37_0  
anaconda-navigator        1.9.7                    py37_0  
anaconda-project          0.8.3                      py_0  
anyqt                     0.0.10                   py37_0  
asn1crypto                0.24.0                   py37_0  
astroid                   2.2.5                    py37_0  
astropy                   3.2.1            py37h7b6447c_0  
atomicwrites              1.3.0                    py37_1  
attrs                     19.1.0                   py37_1  
babel                     2.7.0                      py_0  
backcall                  0.1.0                    py37_0  
backports                 1.0                        py_2  
backports.functools_lru_cache 1.5                        py_2  
backports.os              0.1.1                    py37_0  
backports.shutil_get_terminal_size 1.0.0                    py37_2  
backports.tempfile        1.0                        py_1  
backports.weakref         1.0.post1                  py_1  
beautifulsoup4            4.7.1                    py37_1  
bitarray                  0.9.3            py37h7b6447c_0  
bkcharts                  0.2                      py37_0  
blas                      1.0                         mkl  
bleach                    3.1.0                    py37_0  
blosc                     1.16.3               hd408876_0  
bokeh                     1.2.0                    py37_0  
boto                      2.49.0                   py37_0  
bottleneck                1.2.1            py37h035aef0_1  
bzip2                     1.0.8                h7b6447c_0  
ca-certificates           2020.1.1                      0  
cairo                     1.14.12              h8948797_3  
certifi                   2020.4.5.1               py37_0  
cffi                      1.12.3           py37h2e261b9_0  
chardet                   3.0.4                    py37_1  
click                     7.0                      py37_0  
cloudpickle               1.2.1                      py_0  
clyent                    1.2.2                    py37_1  
colorama                  0.4.1                    py37_0  
conda                     4.8.3                    py37_0  
conda-build               3.18.8                   py37_0  
conda-env                 2.6.0                         1  
conda-package-handling    1.3.11                   py37_0  
conda-verify              3.4.2                      py_1  
contextlib2               0.5.5                    py37_0  
cryptography              2.7              py37h1ba5d50_0  
curl                      7.65.2               hbc83047_0  
cycler                    0.10.0                   py37_0  
cython                    0.29.12          py37he6710b0_0  
cytoolz                   0.10.0           py37h7b6447c_0  
dask                      2.1.0                      py_0  
dask-core                 2.1.0                      py_0  
dbus                      1.13.6               h746ee38_0  
decorator                 4.4.0                    py37_1  
defusedxml                0.6.0                      py_0  
distributed               2.1.0                      py_0  
docutils                  0.14                     py37_0  
entrypoints               0.3                      py37_0  
et_xmlfile                1.0.1                    py37_0  
expat                     2.2.6                he6710b0_0  
fastcache                 1.1.0            py37h7b6447c_0  
filelock                  3.0.12                     py_0  
flask                     1.1.1                      py_0  
fontconfig                2.13.0               h9420a91_0  
freetype                  2.9.1                h8a8886c_1  
fribidi                   1.0.5                h7b6447c_0  
future                    0.17.1                   py37_0  
get_terminal_size         1.0.0                haa9412d_0  
gevent                    1.4.0            py37h7b6447c_0  
glib                      2.56.2               hd408876_0  
glob2                     0.7                        py_0  
gmp                       6.1.2                h6c8ec71_1  
gmpy2                     2.0.8            py37h10f8cd9_2  
graphite2                 1.3.13               h23475e2_0  
graphviz                  2.40.1               h21bd128_2    anaconda
greenlet                  0.4.15           py37h7b6447c_0  
gst-plugins-base          1.14.0               hbbd80ab_1  
gstreamer                 1.14.0               hb453b48_1  
h5py                      2.9.0            py37h7918eee_0  
harfbuzz                  1.8.8                hffaf4a1_0  
hdf5                      1.10.4               hb1b8bf9_0  
heapdict                  1.0.0                    py37_2  
html5lib                  1.0.1                    py37_0  
icu                       58.2                 h9c2bf20_1  
idna                      2.8                      py37_0  
imageio                   2.5.0                    py37_0  
imagesize                 1.1.0                    py37_0  
importlib_metadata        0.17                     py37_1  
intel-openmp              2019.4                      243  
ipykernel                 5.1.1            py37h39e3cac_0  
ipython                   7.6.1            py37h39e3cac_0  
ipython_genutils          0.2.0                    py37_0  
ipywidgets                7.5.0                      py_0  
isort                     4.3.21                   py37_0  
itsdangerous              1.1.0                    py37_0  
jbig                      2.1                  hdba287a_0  
jdcal                     1.4.1                      py_0  
jedi                      0.13.3                   py37_0  
jeepney                   0.4                      py37_0  
jinja2                    2.10.1                   py37_0  
joblib                    0.13.2                   py37_0  
jpeg                      9b                   h024ee3a_2  
json5                     0.8.4                      py_0  
jsonschema                3.0.1                    py37_0  
jupyter                   1.0.0                    py37_7  
jupyter_client            5.3.1                      py_0  
jupyter_console           6.0.0                    py37_0  
jupyter_core              4.5.0                      py_0  
jupyterlab                1.0.2            py37hf63ae98_0  
jupyterlab_server         1.0.0                      py_0  
keyring                   18.0.0                   py37_0  
kiwisolver                1.1.0            py37he6710b0_0  
krb5                      1.16.1               h173b8e3_7  
lazy-object-proxy         1.4.1            py37h7b6447c_0  
libarchive                3.3.3                h5d8350f_5  
libcurl                   7.65.2               h20c2e04_0  
libedit                   3.1.20181209         hc058e9b_0  
libffi                    3.2.1                hd88cf55_4  
libgcc-ng                 9.1.0                hdf63c60_0  
libgfortran-ng            7.3.0                hdf63c60_0  
liblief                   0.9.0                h7725739_2  
libpng                    1.6.37               hbc83047_0  
libsodium                 1.0.16               h1bed415_0  
libssh2                   1.8.2                h1ba5d50_0  
libstdcxx-ng              9.1.0                hdf63c60_0  
libtiff                   4.0.10               h2733197_2  
libtool                   2.4.6                h7b6447c_5  
libuuid                   1.0.3                h1bed415_2  
libxcb                    1.13                 h1bed415_1  
libxml2                   2.9.9                hea5a465_1  
libxslt                   1.1.33               h7d1a2b0_0  
llvmlite                  0.29.0           py37hd408876_0  
locket                    0.2.0                    py37_1  
lxml                      4.3.4            py37hefd8a0e_0  
lz4-c                     1.8.1.2              h14c3975_0  
lzo                       2.10                 h49e0be7_2  
markupsafe                1.1.1            py37h7b6447c_0  
matplotlib                3.1.0            py37h5429711_0  
mccabe                    0.6.1                    py37_1  
mistune                   0.8.4            py37h7b6447c_0  
mkl                       2019.4                      243  
mkl-service               2.0.2            py37h7b6447c_0  
mkl_fft                   1.0.12           py37ha843d7b_0  
mkl_random                1.0.2            py37hd81dba3_0  
mock                      3.0.5                    py37_0  
more-itertools            7.0.0                    py37_0  
mpc                       1.1.0                h10f8cd9_1  
mpfr                      4.0.1                hdf1c602_3  
mpmath                    1.1.0                    py37_0  
msgpack-python            0.6.1            py37hfd86e86_1  
multipledispatch          0.6.0                    py37_0  
navigator-updater         0.2.1                    py37_0  
nbconvert                 5.5.0                      py_0  
nbformat                  4.4.0                    py37_0  
ncurses                   6.1                  he6710b0_1  
networkx                  2.3                        py_0  
nltk                      3.4.4                    py37_0  
nose                      1.3.7                    py37_2  
notebook                  6.0.0                    py37_0  
numba                     0.44.1           py37h962f231_0  
numexpr                   2.6.9            py37h9e4a6bb_0  
numpy                     1.16.4           py37h7e9f1db_0  
numpy-base                1.16.4           py37hde5b4d6_0  
numpydoc                  0.9.1                      py_0  
olefile                   0.46                     py37_0  
openpyxl                  2.6.2                      py_0  
openssl                   1.1.1g               h7b6447c_0  
packaging                 19.0                     py37_0  
pandas                    0.24.2           py37he6710b0_0  
pandoc                    2.2.3.2                       0  
pandocfilters             1.4.2                    py37_1  
pango                     1.42.4               h049681c_0  
parso                     0.5.0                      py_0  
partd                     1.0.0                      py_0  
patchelf                  0.9                  he6710b0_3  
path.py                   12.0.1                     py_0  
pathlib2                  2.3.4                    py37_0  
patsy                     0.5.1                    py37_0  
pcre                      8.43                 he6710b0_0  
pep8                      1.7.1                    py37_0  
pexpect                   4.7.0                    py37_0  
pickleshare               0.7.5                    py37_0  
pillow                    6.1.0            py37h34e0f95_0  
pip                       19.1.1                   py37_0  
pixman                    0.38.0               h7b6447c_0  
pkginfo                   1.5.0.1                  py37_0  
pluggy                    0.12.0                     py_0  
ply                       3.11                     py37_0  
prometheus_client         0.7.1                      py_0  
prompt_toolkit            2.0.9                    py37_0  
psutil                    5.6.3            py37h7b6447c_0  
ptyprocess                0.6.0                    py37_0  
py                        1.8.0                    py37_0  
py-lief                   0.9.0            py37h7725739_2  
pycodestyle               2.5.0                    py37_0  
pycosat                   0.6.3            py37h14c3975_0  
pycparser                 2.19                     py37_0  
pycrypto                  2.6.1            py37h14c3975_9  
pycurl                    7.43.0.3         py37h1ba5d50_0  
pyflakes                  2.1.1                    py37_0  
pygments                  2.4.2                      py_0  
pylint                    2.3.1                    py37_0  
pyodbc                    4.0.26           py37he6710b0_0  
pyopenssl                 19.0.0                   py37_0  
pyparsing                 2.4.0                      py_0  
pyqt                      5.9.2            py37h05f1152_2  
pyqtgraph                 0.10.0           py37h28b3542_3  
pyrsistent                0.14.11          py37h7b6447c_0  
pysocks                   1.7.0                    py37_0  
pytables                  3.5.2            py37h71ec239_1  
pytest                    5.0.1                    py37_0  
pytest-arraydiff          0.3              py37h39e3cac_0  
pytest-astropy            0.5.0                    py37_0  
pytest-doctestplus        0.3.0                    py37_0  
pytest-openfiles          0.3.2                    py37_0  
pytest-remotedata         0.3.1                    py37_0  
python                    3.7.3                h0371630_0  
python-dateutil           2.8.0                    py37_0  
python-graphviz           0.10.1                     py_0  
python-libarchive-c       2.8                     py37_11  
pytz                      2019.1                     py_0  
pywavelets                1.0.3            py37hdd07704_1  
pyyaml                    5.1.1            py37h7b6447c_0  
pyzmq                     18.0.0           py37he6710b0_0  
qt                        5.9.7                h5867ecd_1  
qtawesome                 0.5.7                    py37_1  
qtconsole                 4.5.1                      py_0  
qtpy                      1.8.0                      py_0  
readline                  7.0                  h7b6447c_5  
requests                  2.22.0                   py37_0  
rope                      0.14.0                     py_0  
ruamel_yaml               0.15.46          py37h14c3975_0  
scikit-image              0.15.0           py37he6710b0_0  
scikit-learn              0.21.2           py37hd81dba3_0  
scipy                     1.3.0            py37h7c811a0_0  
seaborn                   0.9.0                    py37_0  
secretstorage             3.1.1                    py37_0  
send2trash                1.5.0                    py37_0  
setuptools                41.0.1                   py37_0  
simplegeneric             0.8.1                    py37_2  
singledispatch            3.4.0.3                  py37_0  
sip                       4.19.8           py37hf484d3e_0  
six                       1.12.0                   py37_0  
snappy                    1.1.7                hbae5bb6_3  
snowballstemmer           1.9.0                      py_0  
sortedcollections         1.1.2                    py37_0  
sortedcontainers          2.1.0                    py37_0  
soupsieve                 1.8                      py37_0  
sphinx                    2.1.2                      py_0  
sphinxcontrib             1.0                      py37_1  
sphinxcontrib-applehelp   1.0.1                      py_0  
sphinxcontrib-devhelp     1.0.1                      py_0  
sphinxcontrib-htmlhelp    1.0.2                      py_0  
sphinxcontrib-jsmath      1.0.1                      py_0  
sphinxcontrib-qthelp      1.0.2                      py_0  
sphinxcontrib-serializinghtml 1.1.3                      py_0  
sphinxcontrib-websupport  1.1.2                      py_0  
spyder                    3.3.6                    py37_0  
spyder-kernels            0.5.1                    py37_0  
sqlalchemy                1.3.5            py37h7b6447c_0  
sqlite                    3.29.0               h7b6447c_0  
statsmodels               0.10.0           py37hdd07704_0  
sympy                     1.4                      py37_0  
tbb                       2019.4               hfd86e86_0  
tblib                     1.4.0                      py_0  
terminado                 0.8.2                    py37_0  
testpath                  0.4.2                    py37_0  
tk                        8.6.8                hbc83047_0  
toolz                     0.10.0                     py_0  
tornado                   6.0.3            py37h7b6447c_0  
tqdm                      4.32.1                     py_0  
traitlets                 4.3.2                    py37_0  
unicodecsv                0.14.1                   py37_0  
unixodbc                  2.3.7                h14c3975_0  
urllib3                   1.24.2                   py37_0  
wcwidth                   0.1.7                    py37_0  
webencodings              0.5.1                    py37_1  
werkzeug                  0.15.4                     py_0  
wheel                     0.33.4                   py37_0  
widgetsnbextension        3.5.0                    py37_0  
wrapt                     1.11.2           py37h7b6447c_0  
wurlitzer                 1.0.2                    py37_0  
xlrd                      1.2.0                    py37_0  
xlsxwriter                1.1.8                      py_0  
xlwt                      1.3.0                    py37_0  
xz                        5.2.4                h14c3975_4  
yaml                      0.1.7                had09818_2  
zeromq                    4.3.1                he6710b0_3  
zict                      1.0.0                      py_0  
zipp                      0.5.1                      py_0  
zlib                      1.2.11               h7b6447c_3  
zstd                      1.3.7                h0b5b093_0
```

Comment: Have you run `conda list`? These packages that are installed might be in the global directory and not in the virtualenv itself.

Comment: @ZWang I have edited the output of the `conda list`. I noticed that some packages are from the `conda list` command in the `requirements.txt`. But, how can I exclude them from `pip freeze`?

Comment: The `conda list` you provided isn't of the virtual environment. Are you sure you've activated the environment?

Comment: @ZWang I have updated the list after activating the virtual environment

Answer (score 3):

I was struggling with the same problem. New virtual environments had many unwanted  packages installed, even though some of these are things that I do not even have installed with my system python or any virtual environment. At first I assumed that this must be some local configuration bug, but the list of packages installed is complete identical to the ones that you listed, so it seems more likely that this is a bug in the `virtualenv` package itself.

When I create a new virtualenv it contains the following libraries no matter what:

```
appdirs==1.4.3
CacheControl==0.12.6
certifi==2019.11.28
chardet==3.0.4
colorama==0.4.3
contextlib2==0.6.0
distlib==0.3.0
distro==1.4.0
html5lib==1.0.1
idna==2.8
ipaddr==2.2.0
lockfile==0.12.2
msgpack==0.6.2
packaging==20.3
pep517==0.8.2
progress==1.5
pyparsing==2.4.6
pytoml==0.1.21
requests==2.22.0
retrying==1.3.3
six==1.14.0
urllib3==1.25.8
webencodings==0.5.1
```

I wanted to know why these packages were being installed so that I could disable them, and while looking I found that these packages are all in the folder
`~/.local/share/virtualenv/seed-app-data/v1.0.1.debian/3.8/wheels`
Unfortunately, just removing this folder doesn't work. It's regenerated with the same content, so something else upstream is responsible for the bug. This seems likely to be a packaging error by Ubuntu or something like that.

I am on Ubuntu 20.04 with this version of virtualenv:
`python3-virtualenv/focal,focal,now 20.0.17-1 all` - I never had the issue while on previous versions of Ubuntu. if you have a similar platform that would help confirm the hypothesis.

If you need a workaround, I found that the following method for creating virtual environments still works without including all the unwanted packages:
`python3 -m venv path/to/venv`
(You'll need to run `sudo apt-get install python3-venv` first for this to work)

Comment: Ran into the same issue, purged virtualenv and installed venv. Worked for me, thanks

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had the same problem, created a virtual environment, and exactly appeared the same pre-installed packages within it.

*Data of my system:*

Python 3.8.5

Linux Mint 20.1

Note: I do not have `pip` installed globally on my system, only within virtual environments.

**The solution that worked for me:**

- Unistall python3-virtualenv, including your dependencies

  ```
  $ sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove python3-virtualenv
  ```
- Check that there is no `virtualenv` installed

  ```
  $ virtualenv
  ```
- Should see something similar to this

  ```
  Command 'virtualenv' not found, but it can be installed with:
  sudo apt install python3-virtualenv
  ```
- First, update. Then I install `virtualenv` but not with `python3-virtualenv`. Instead, I use

  ```
  $ sudo apt-get update
  $ sudo apt-get install virtualenv
  ```

The virtualenv will be installed, and the necessary dependencies of Python3 and its appropriate versions.

Now, when I create a virtual environment this is totally empty.
^ u^)b